# Overpass API get nearby building boundaries from a coordinate(lat/lang)

Tags: overpass-api

How can i get the building boundaries with single coordinate using overpass API? Right now i have a coordinate(lat/lang) but with this i would like to get the building boundaries for that perticular coordinates.
Even is it possible to get the building boundaries near by my cordinates(lat/lang) ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achive this is to search buildings within certain radius from your point using **around:** function.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(               // radius, lat, lon
node["building"](around:7.0, 52.2283207, 21.0133141);
way["building"](around:7.0, 52.2283207, 21.0133141);
relation["building"](around:7.0, 52.2283207, 21.0133141);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```